# Execute code if a test fails with py.test

Tags: android, python, adb, pytest

I'm doing UI test automation on Android using [Appium](http://appium.io/) and [py.test](http://pytest.org/latest/). I'd like to be able to save a bug report using [adb](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#commandsummary) after a test fails.

Is there a way to tell if a test fails in my test code so I can then run save the bug report in the teardown?

Originally, I was just going to save the bug report after each test, but it's a bit excessive adding 45 seconds to each test.

Comment: Did you look into considering to start a subprocess to monitor adb logs in python? If that's what exactly you want

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can implement a `pytest_runtest_logreport` hook in your `conftest.py` like this:

```
def pytest_runtest_logreport(report):
    if report.when == 'call' and report.failed:
        # save bug report
```

For more information, see [Woking with plugins and conftest files](http://pytest.org/latest/plugins.html).