# Is it possible to pass a parameter to a teardown fixture in python?

Tags: python, pytest, finalizer, fixture, teardown

I have bunch of test methods that i need to run and then after each test i want to update my results somewhere else.
This is what i have:

```
@pytest.mark.testcasename('1234')
@pytest.mark.parametrize('lang',
                         ["EN", "FR"])
def test_text(self, request, base_url, lang):
    testrail_conn = TestrailHelper()
    test_case_id = request.node.get_marker("testcasename").args[0]
    base_url = base_url.replace("testEN", "testFR") if lang == "FR" else base_url
    self.navigate(base_url)
    self.wait_for_page_loaded()
    results = self.check_text(lang)
    try:
        assert results
        testrail_conn.update_test_status(test_case_id, test_result=1)
    except AssertionError:
        testrail_conn.update_test_status(test_case_id, test_result=5)
```

My problem is that i want the update_test_status to be in a teardown fixture where i can pass my test_result to it. This way i dont need to write same code for each test method..
Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You can always store stuff on the `TestCase` instance.  That way it will be available during tear down.  I don't think that would be the best abstraction to use in this case.  How about a custom decorator or context manager?

Comment: @SvenMarnach is right

Comment: have a look at some of the plugin hooks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26259990/execute-code-if-a-test-fails-with-py-test has a nice example

Comment: Thanks @SvenMarnach. Ill try that. i just thought i can use the fixtures in py.test to make it work

Comment: @SvenMarnach a `TestCase` instance typically isn't available with pytest, which can work with simple functions rather than enforcing classes.

Comment: @TheCompiler: I never used pytest.  I was just deducing there must be an instance since the function has a `self` parameter and accesses attributes on it.

Comment: @SvenMarnach oh, indeed - I didn't notice! So yeah, in this case, I guess both would work.

Comment: may be just write own assert method

Answer (score 0):

You could store something on the `request` object, e.g. on `request.node` - see [the docs](http://pytest.org/latest/builtin.html#_pytest.python.FixtureRequest). Alternatively, you could use your fixture (as an argument) from the test, and store something there - or make the fixture return/yield some kind of data structure to store things in.

Comment: this would be useful with a coded example for either using request.node or with a fixture using yield.